# Highcharts non linear xAxis in polar series

Tags: charts, highcharts

Is anybody know how to specify the weight of different categories in Xaxis in a polar chart ? 
I would like for exemple my "Apples" category to be twice bigger than oranges.

Put another way, I want to mix pie charts and polar charts in order to have two dimension visualisation (category weigth in Xaxis and production in Yaxis).

Any idea would be appreciated

[image: My polar chart]

Here a little fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lcs8foev/

My Code :

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        polar: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360
    },


    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums']


    },

            plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Production in tons',
        data: [80, 70, 60, 50, 40],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }]
});
```

});

Comment: You can define multiple yAxis and set a proper min/max for them. Then create the corresponded series which are linked to the proper axis. One last thing is setting grouping to false, so the additional space for null points will not be created. http://jsfiddle.net/Lcs8foev/1/

Comment: Thanks for this first shot but actually I don't need to change the yAxis.
I would like to change the size of each "slice" : Having "Apple" representing half my circle (50%) and the other 12.5% each for exemple.

Comment: I don't think there is a bult-in option for doing this. You need to manually set point width, axis scale, labels positions, etc. http://jsfiddle.net/Lcs8foev/11/ However, some options like pointPlacement does not work as I expect